# Why does maven use my internal repository before my local repository?

Tags: maven-2, maven

when I am doing development I often need to change a dependency, but I'm not ready to deploy my changes.  For example, I'm working on project Foo and I realize I need to add a method to the common library.  Before deploying this change to our internal repository, I would like to install the changes to common library (`mvn install`) and recompile Foo to use the common library in the local repository (note that I'm using all SNAPSHOT versions).

However, after I `mvn install` my common library, when I recompile Foo it doesn't use the new common library--it keeps using the latest SNAPSHOT of common library in the internal repository.  If I deploy the changed common library, Foo picks it up immediately.

How can I get maven to look first in the local repository?

UPDATE: when the file is installed into the local repository, it gets a name like `foo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but when I deploy it, it gets a timestamp `foo-1.0.0-20111104.191316-23.jar`.  I think this is why the remote artifact gets pulled each time.  Any idea why `mvn install` is not working like `mvn deploy`?  Does it have to do with the fact that I have a snapshot repository set up for deploy?

Comment: Do you have a `localRepository` in your [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) that points to a non-existent location?

Comment: Compare your system date to the date of your internal repo (e.g. Nexus) system. If it's a long way ahead, its timestamps will "win"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Maven checks for new versions of SNAPSHOT artifacts once per day. When it does this check, it will download SNAPSHOTS from remote repos that are newer than what you have locally. Either your artifact timestamps are out of sync and you're doing something to override Maven's update policy (like [calling it with -U](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mvn/) or [setting the udpatePolicy](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) to "always"), or else the local repository you're installing the artifact to isn't the same one you're subsequently running Maven against. What you're describing isn't typical Maven behavior. For a better answer, give more details in your question.

One indicator you can look for: after you install your common artifact, when you next compile Foo, does Maven download the common artifact again? If so, then it really is getting it from the remote, and you need to check your update settings. If not, then you have something strange going on locally.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, clearly nobody will be able to tell me exactly what's going on without more details.  It's helpful to know that this isn't standard behaviour in the first place so I can investigate further!

Comment: I added some more details--see my UPDATE at the end of my question.

Comment: For a while now, Maven has used timestamps to uniquely identify snapshot versions deployed to a remote repo, and "SNAPSHOT" is simply an alias for the most recent of these timestamped artifacts. I think it was somewhere around 2.1.0 that that started? It doesn't change anything about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option. This worked for me.

In your project's main pom.xml change 'snapshots' enabled setting to 'false'.

```
<repository>
    <id>yourRepo</id>
    <name>Repository</name>
    <url>http://your.repo.com/repo</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```